# Creatives LinkedIn API - Projection parameters not supported with new versioned API

Tags: linkedin-api

`Hi All,

After LinkedIn API versioning, it seems that below projection parameter is not supported with creatives API call now :

1. com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredVideoCreativeVariables
2. com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCarouselCreativeVariables
3. com.linkedin.ads.SpotlightCreativeVariablesV2
4. com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredUpdateCreativeVariables
5. com.linkedin.ads.JobsCreativeVariablesV2
6. com.linkedin.ads.SponsoredInMailCreativeVariables

Due to this, we are not able to fetch response similar to Old API call with new API now. This seems to be big impact to us.

For example , We are not receiving any of fields like 'showMemberProfilePhoto', 'forumName' for SpotlightCreativeVariablesV2 with new API which we used to get previously like mentioned below.
We have 2 headers in request as mentioned in LinkedIn API migration document.

1. X-Restli-Protocol-Version : 2.0.0
2. LinkedIn-Version : 202210

**Old API call** : [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2?ids=List({$creative_id})&projection=(results(*(variables(*,data(*,com.linkedin.ads.SpotlightCreativeVariablesV2(*,share~(*)))))))](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2?ids=List(%7B$creative_id%7D)&projection=(results(*(variables(*,data(*,com.linkedin.ads.SpotlightCreativeVariablesV2(*,share%7E(*))))))))
**Old API Response :**

```
{
    "results": {
        "46524875": {
            "variables": {
                "clickUri": "$clickUri",
                "data": {
                    "com.linkedin.ads.SpotlightCreativeVariablesV2": {
                        "showMemberProfilePhoto": true,
                        "forumName": "$forumName",
                        "description": "$description",
                        "logo": "$logo",
                        "headline": "$headline",
                        "callToAction": "$callToAction"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**New API Call** : [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/creatives?ids=List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCreative%3A{$creative_id})](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/creatives?ids=List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCreative%3A%7B$creative_id%7D))
**New API Response** :

```
{
    "results": {
        "urn:li:sponsoredCreative:$creative_id": {
            "servingHoldReasons": ["$servingHoldReasons"],
            "lastModifiedAt": 12345678000,
            "lastModifiedBy": "",
            "content": {
                "reference": "urn:li:ugcPost:$ugc_post"
            },
            "createdAt": 1234562340000,
            "isTest": false,
            "createdBy": "$createdBy",
            "review": {
                "status": "APPROVED"
            },
            "isServing": false,
            "campaign": "urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:$campaign_id",
            "id": "urn:li:sponsoredCreative:$creative_id",
            "intendedStatus": "ACTIVE",
            "account": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:$account_id"
        }
    },
    "statuses": {
        "urn:li:sponsoredCreative:creative_id": 200
    },
    "errors": {}
}
```

Is there any way to get all those fields we used to get in old API call with new API as we need these fields for processing.

`